# OKD 3.10: standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "permission denied"

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Attempting to create a new-app using the following image from DockerHub along with a floating license provided by Smartbear running on a box in the nextwork:

smartbear/ready-api-virtserver

Running on Ubuntu 18:04
Docker version 18.09.0-ce-tp4, build 33764aa
OpenShift 3.10

Used the following command to create the new-app

oc new-app smartbear/ready-api-virtserver ACCEPT_TOU=true VirtServerLicenseServer=X.X.X.X:1099 DockerUser=1001 VirtServerUser=admin VirtServerPassword=128e123812

The Pod log shows the error in the subject. The Deployment log shows the error:

--> Scaling ready-api-virtserver-1 to 1

The Deployment attempts many times to execute and returns the same Pod and Deployment logs.

Comment: At a guess, the image is set up to run as ``root``. OpenShift by default blocks you from running containers as ``root``.

Comment: Worked around it by loosening up the service account policy. Will see if we can get the User in the Dockerfile to run as something else going forward.